# Php ratchet async loop

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

Is it possible to run the loop asynchronously? I tried it with Promise class, but it still runs synchronously with all the other queries

```
        $webServer = new \Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
            new \Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
                new \Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                    // new \Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                        $socketClass
                    // )
                )
            ),
            $webSock
        );
        $promise = new \React\Promise\Promise(function($resolve){
            $resolve(info("START"));
        });
        $promise->then(function($v) use ($loop, $socketClass) {
            $loop->addPeriodicTimer(0.1, function () use ($socketClass) {
                $socketClass->roundsTicker();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Depends precisely what you mean by asynchronously. PHP is single-threaded, so there is no true async really in PHP. Describe in more detail what behaviour you wanted / expected from the code, and what you actually got.

Comment: I use stack laravel + ratchet for websockets.
I need a periodic timer that will send messages every 0.1s (just the timer, nothing else), but also need it to work in some kind of pseudo asynchronous (understand that it does not exist in php), or change the logic of the queue (but there is also the problem that the queue is not instantaneous (driver - redis), which is extremely critical in my case).

Comment: Ok thanks. I would suggest maybe having a separate PHP script (which would be running in a separate thread) which has a client connection to the websocket server, and sends messages to it every 0.1 seconds. Right now, it looks like all your server and client code is in one script.

Comment: Thank you, I had that idea too, but was stuck on how to get all the connections from outside the socket

Comment: You'll need a php websocket client - there are some libraries on github I think

Comment: Thank you, the solution helped. But there is another thing that came up after it, because I have a cycle and every 0.1s message is sent, then during this cycle if the user sends his message, there will be a microfreeze (because of the sync onmessage function), is it possible to do something to avoid this?

Comment: TBH if you want that level of accuracy I'd suggest using something a bit more professional and genuinely multithreaded, maybe something like SignalR would he useful to you. You can host it very cheaply in the cloud. You don't necessarily need to know c# but it makes it a bit easier. No guarantees of course, but certainly it's designed around asynchronous programming in a way that php just isn't